# how to create a local repo in ubuntu with specific packages that will serve update and installation request from client machines of all the distros

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, localrepository

I can only create a local repo by downloading the whole mirror repository. i want to make the repo only for specific packages not all the packages. i would also want this centos machine to have repo for centos and other distros. The repos will be updated and client machines will receive updates from this server with no access to internet. like WSUS. i would really appreciate your help finding a solution

i have downloaded some specific packages into the ubuntu server 22.04 LTS and put it in the /var/www/html/loca_repo folder and configured the /etc/apt/sources.list in the client machine to install and receive updates from this server only, but its not working.

Comment: `apt-cacher-ng` for Ubuntu and others, and look on CentOS forums for their corresponding solution

Answer (score -1):

It is necessary to have the Apache server installed.
Assuming your ip address is 192.168.0.23
We verify that it is correctly installed by entering with the web browser, http://192.168.0.23
The Apache server stores its entire structure in the /var/www/ path and the website is stored in the /var/www/html/ path.
Being in the /var/www/ path we will create the debs folder and within it the amd64 and i386 folders.
Once this structure is created, it is necessary to execute the following commands to configure the APT catalog:
In the amd64 folder:

```
dpkg-scanpackages amd64 | gzip -9c > Packages.gz
```

In the i386 folder:

```
dpkg-scanpackages i386 | gzip -9c > Packages.gz
```

In the sources.list file it is necessary to add the IP address of the server where the repository has been created:

```
deb http://192.168.0.23/debs/ amd64/

deb http://192.168.0.23/debs/ i386/
```

Any user who has the sources.list repository configured in this way could have access to the local APT packages